# Access-Control-Allow-Origin response with ETag header seems to be getting cached despite response also having Vary: Origin

Tags: cors, apache2, rack-cors

I have a rails API serving mywebsite.com and app.mywebsite.com with rack-cors configured to allow me to make requests from both. The API sits at api.mywebsite.com.

If I make a call to an endpoint from mywebsite.com everything works as expected. However, if I then make the same call from app.myswebsite.com I get the error:

`Access to fetch at 'https://api.mywebsite.com/api/v1/endpoint' from origin 'https://app.mywebsite.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://mywebsite.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin.`

I have set debug in rack-cors and can see the correct Access-Control-Allow-Origin is sending the correct header, it just doesn't seem to make it to the browser.

I've found if I clear my cache then I'm able to successfully make the call from app.mywebsite.com but then receive the error from mywebsite.com:

`Access to fetch at 'https://api.mywebsite.com/api/v1/endpoint' from origin 'https://mywebsite.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://app.mywebsite.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin.`

So in short, my browser seems to be caching the first 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header it receives.

I've read I need to set the Vary response header but I already have this set to Origin.

edit:
request headers from working request (mywebsite.com)

```
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Cookie: _my_website_session=abc123
Host: api.mywebsite.com
Origin: https://mywebsite.com
Referer: https://mywebsite.com/
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="95", "Chromium";v="95", ";Not A Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.54 Safari/537.36
```

response headers from working request (mywebsite.com)

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://mywebsite.com
Access-Control-Expose-Headers
Access-Control-Max-Age: 7200
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 22 Oct 2021 09:19:31 GMT
ETag: W/"ceb3066459b786782d836ac9e51cd349"
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: _my_website_session=abc123; path=/; HttpOnly
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
X-Request-Id: 8fefc93c-b320-4276-acd4-8177b7745068
X-Runtime: 0.021539
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Request headers from erroring request (app.mywebsite.com):

```
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Cookie: _my_website_session=abc_123
Host: api.mywebsite.com
If-None-Match: W/"ceb3066459b786782d836ac9e51cd349"
Origin: https://app.mywebsite.com
Referer: https://app.mywebsite.com/
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="95", "Chromium";v="95", ";Not A Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.54 Safari/537.36
```

Response Headers from erroring request (app.mywebsite.com)

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://mywebsite.com
Access-Control-Expose-Headers
Access-Control-Max-Age: 7200
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 22 Oct 2021 09:19:32 GMT
ETag: W/"ceb3066459b786782d836ac9e51cd349"
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: _my_website_session=abc123; path=/; HttpOnly
Vary: Origin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
X-Request-Id: 8fefc93c-b320-4276-acd4-8177b7745068
X-Runtime: 0.021539
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Edit 2
This problem exists on Chrome on Mac. Everything works as expected on Safari
I can also see the request hitting the controller correctly, it's just the response in the user agent that seems to be the problem.

Comment: @sideshowbarker it looks to be the same as this report: [link]https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=983532[/link]
and not considered a bug due to the ETag headers matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got to the bottom of this.

Chrome will still use the cached header even if the origins differ and the Vary header is present and set to 'Origin' if the ETags still match.

To get past this either unset the ETag header or vary it based on request origin.

Comment: A couple more questions: Are you sending the Vary response header in every single response you send out for that `https://api.mywebsite.com/api/v1/endpoint` route? I mean, not just for the CORS-enabled responses, but for all responses, regardless. If not, you need to be.

Comment: Incidentally, another thing: if I’m not mistaken, you seem to be sending out the same ETag header even when another response header has changed. If any response headers change, the response should get a different ETag.

Comment: @sideshowbarker
Yeah the Very header is present for all requests from the API.

And yes, you're right the ETag should change if the response headers change.  In this instance I don't require caching so unsettling the ETag works fine. In the long term, I may need to come back to this and fix the ETag, but hopefully, this answer will point anyone else facing the same issue in the right direction.

Comment: OK yeah, so https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=983532#c7 seems to make it pretty clear that what‘s described in the question is caused by the responses having the same ETag header value despite the fact they have different Access-Control-Allow-Origin header values.